# Story that includes Sokka bringing fruit to Momo's grave

Tags: story-identification, avatar-the-last-airbender

I saw an image a while ago from what looked to be a comic about the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* series after the show. The image showed Sokka delivering peaches and other fruit to the grave of Momo and thanking him for his friendship.

Comment: This image? https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c6/fd/40/c6fd4094bfa57095f6ce5e9ce4072aa8.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reckon it could be this illustration from "nukilik-fandom (monicapra)", if I am to believe [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/49jxoq/fan_content_its_been_a_while_buddy_by/).

[image: Sokka on Momo's grave]

[One of the comments there](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/49jxoq/fan_content_its_been_a_while_buddy_by/d0scjvl) states:

> As far as I can tell the artist has deleted this comic from their [blog](http://monicapra.tumblr.com/) . If you know otherwise please don't hesitate to tell me.

For what it's worth, the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://monicapra.tumblr.com/) has [a single snapshot of this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202052856/http://monicapra.tumblr.com/), and it's not one with the illustration.

---

Found with the Google Images query `sokka grave momo fruit`.

Comment: Thats the one. I need to work on my Google game. I tried ´sokka momo funeral´  close but no cigar. Thanks!